# Error: Not found wrapperScript: D:\a\1\s\gradlew

Tags: android, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm creating an Azure Devops pipeline for my Android repository which is on Bitbucket. I have created a classic pipeline. I have setup continuous integration by following various steps following this blog post:
https://itnext.io/how-to-setup-ci-cd-pipelines-for-android-with-azure-devops-2a4ded0de0e7

Before proceeding with CD, I wanted to run the pipeline. So I ran the pipeline and faced the below Error:
Error: Not found wrapperScript: D:\a\1\s\gradlew

I'm adding the raw log file for your reference. I searched online for a solution and to my disappointment, I couldn't find a working solution. Please help. Find the log file below

> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.6666771Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step:
> 'gradlew buildRelease' 2022-02-07T12:25:24.6668643Z
> ##[debug]Evaluating: succeeded() 2022-02-07T12:25:24.6669141Z ##[debug]Evaluating succeeded: 2022-02-07T12:25:24.6670247Z ##[debug]=> True 2022-02-07T12:25:24.6670740Z ##[debug]Result: True 2022-02-07T12:25:24.6671294Z ##[section]Starting: gradlew buildRelease
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.6783754Z
> ============================================================================== 2022-02-07T12:25:24.6784050Z Task         : Gradle
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.6784257Z Description  : Build using a Gradle
> wrapper script 2022-02-07T12:25:24.6784478Z Version      : 3.198.0
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.6784667Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.6784956Z Help         :
> https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.6785279Z
> ============================================================================== 2022-02-07T12:25:24.7052847Z ##[debug]Using node path:
> C:\agents\2.198.2\externals\node10\bin\node.exe
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8527724Z ##[debug]agent.TempDirectory=D:\a_temp
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8551469Z ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8568842Z ##[debug]loading
> ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8583719Z ##[debug]loading
> ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8586465Z
> ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8588710Z ##[debug]loading
> INPUT_CHECKSTYLEANALYSISENABLED 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8590512Z
> ##[debug]loading INPUT_CLASSFILESDIRECTORIES 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8592099Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CODECOVERAGETOOL
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8593560Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CWD
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8595038Z ##[debug]loading
> INPUT_FAILIFCOVERAGEEMPTY 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8596499Z
> ##[debug]loading INPUT_FINDBUGSANALYSISENABLED 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8597942Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_GRADLE5XORHIGHER
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8599413Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_GRADLEOPTS
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8600881Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_JAVAHOMESELECTION
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8602279Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_JDKARCHITECTURE
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8603715Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_JDKVERSION
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8605152Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_PMDANALYSISENABLED
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8606525Z ##[debug]loading
> INPUT_PUBLISHJUNITRESULTS 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8607917Z
> ##[debug]loading INPUT_SPOTBUGSANALYSISENABLED 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8609416Z ##[debug]loading
> INPUT_SPOTBUGSGRADLEPLUGINVERSION 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8610867Z
> ##[debug]loading INPUT_SPOTBUGSGRADLEPLUGINVERSIONCHOICE 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8612211Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SQANALYSISENABLED
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8613592Z ##[debug]loading
> INPUT_SQGRADLEPLUGINVERSION 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8614946Z
> ##[debug]loading INPUT_SQGRADLEPLUGINVERSIONCHOICE 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8616200Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_TASKS
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8617526Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_TESTRESULTSFILES
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8618917Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_WRAPPERSCRIPT
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8625809Z ##[debug]loaded 25
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8705719Z ##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8707003Z ##[debug]Agent.CAInfo=undefined
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8707814Z ##[debug]Agent.ClientCert=undefined
> 2022-02-07T12:25:24.8708734Z
> ##[debug]Agent.SkipCertValidation=undefined 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0132101Z ##[debug]check path :
> D:\a_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\3.198.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-codecoverage-tools\module.json 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0135127Z ##[debug]adding resource file:
> D:\a_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\3.198.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-codecoverage-tools\module.json 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0136145Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
> 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0177088Z ##[debug]Resource file has already set
> to:
> D:\a_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\3.198.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-codecoverage-tools\module.json 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0183934Z ##[debug]Resource file has already set
> to:
> D:\a_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\3.198.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-codecoverage-tools\module.json 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0191436Z ##[debug]Resource file has already set
> to:
> D:\a_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\3.198.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-codecoverage-tools\module.json 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0206150Z ##[debug]Resource file has already set
> to:
> D:\a_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\3.198.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-codecoverage-tools\module.json 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0213723Z ##[debug]Resource file has already set
> to:
> D:\a_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\3.198.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-codecoverage-tools\module.json 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0500114Z ##[debug]check path :
> D:\a_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\3.198.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-java-common\lib.json
> 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0501427Z ##[debug]adding resource file:
> D:\a_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\3.198.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-java-common\lib.json
> 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0502355Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
> 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0515301Z ##[debug]check path :
> D:\a_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\3.198.0\task.json
> 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0516298Z ##[debug]adding resource file:
> D:\a_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\3.198.0\task.json
> 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0517122Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
> 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0534237Z ##[debug]wrapperScript=D:\a\1\s\gradlew
> 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0534980Z ##[debug]check path : D:\a\1\s\gradlew
> 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0538217Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
> 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0565952Z ##[error]Error: Not found wrapperScript:
> D:\a\1\s\gradlew 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0575454Z ##[debug]Processed:
> ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: Not found wrapperScript: D:\a\1\s\gradlew 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0582600Z ##[debug]Processed:
> ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Error: Not found wrapperScript: D:\a\1\s\gradlew 2022-02-07T12:25:25.0620465Z ##[section]Finishing:
> gradlew buildRelease

Answer (score 1):

From the error it seems the gradle task is unable to find the gradlew script in pipeline working directory. If your gradlew script is located in root, you can leave **Working directory** field empty, it would take gradlew script from root. But in case its located inside subpath e.g. TestPath, you have to specify the absolute path in this way and it should find the gradlew scipt.

```
- task: Gradle@3
  displayName: 'gradlew build'
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/TestPath'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Not found wrapperScript: D:\a\1\s\gradlew

Based on the error message, the Gradle task couldn't find the gradlew file in the source folder.

You need to check the gradlew file path in your repo. Then you can modify the field:**Gradle wrapper** in Gradle  task.

For example:

gradlew file path:

[image]

Gradle task:

[image]

You can also select the file in the task with **...** Option.

For example:

[image]

Comment: I found the gradlew file in the app folder. so I changed the Gradle wrapper to app/gradlew. Still facing the same issue

Comment: @NeerajaGandla Have you tried to use the **...** option in the task to select the file? Please check if it can work

Comment: I tried that too. Still facing the same issue

Comment: @NeerajaGandla, How did you fix it?

Comment: I did not continue with azure devops. So I did not fix it